# how to do negation of Any()

Tags: c#, linq

given the following classes

```
class Order {
  List<Task> Tasks;
}

class Task {
  List<TaskDetail> TaskDetails;
}

class TaskDetail {
  bool ThisDetailFinishesTheTask;
}
```

**How can I get all Orders that have at least one task that has no TaskDetail with `ThisDetailFinishesTheTask`?**

I tried the following, but it is the "inverse" of what I need:

```
Iqueryable<Order> Orders = dbcontext.Orders;
Orders.Where(o => o.Tasks.Any(t => t.TaskDetails.Any(td => td.ThisDetailFinishesTheTask)));
Orders.Load();
```

I think I am close but I just don't see it...

Comment: As with any boolean value, the return value of Any() is negated by the boolean "not" operator, `!`: `!t.TaskDetails.Any(td => td.ThisDetailFinishesTheTask)`. You don't need to compare a boolean to true. "Is it true that this value is true"? Yes. "Is it true that it is true that it is true that this true value is true?" You betcha.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks!
I removed the boolean comparison (I thought it would make it more clear what I was doing; I know that it is redundant)

Comment: @intrixius I think the value of having `== true` or `== false` varies with experience.  Early in my career I liked having it; but now, having worked professionally for 15+ years, I prefer it without.

Comment: @EdPlunkett If you could write an answer I will accept that as the correct answer.

Comment: @intrixius Conner can have it.

Comment: Your class named `Task` could be confused with a synonymous [built-in class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, did you really take the time to write a comment about that? My sample classes are really clear that there will be no confusion. I know that `Task` is a built in class... also `Order` can be confused with "Order" as in "Order By"...

Comment: I was not confused by the `Order`, but the `Task` certainly confused me.

Answer (score 2):

You can not "`!`" the output of any or compare to false similar to how you compared to true.

```
Iqueryable<Order> Orders = dbcontext.Orders;
Orders.Where(o => o.Tasks.Any(t => !t.TaskDetails.Any(td => td.ThisDetailFinishesTheTask == true)));
Orders.Load();
```

Comment: you put the `!` in front of the `o.Tasks.Any`, but I think it should be in front of `t.TaskDetails.Any` as EdPlunkett suggests, no? Or does it make no difference?

Comment: upon rereading it, that does seem correct, I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

> *"how to do negation of Any()"*

In your case, I believe that the "negation" of `Any(x => condition)` is `All(x => !condition)`, because while `Any` will return `true` as soon as it finds one item in a collection that meets a condition, `All` will only return true if every item meets the condition. So if we pass it the opposite condition, we go from "at least one has some thing" to "none have that thing".

> *"How can I get all Orders that have at least one task that has no TaskDetail with ThisDetailFinishesTheTask"*

You can filter on orders who have `Any` tasks where `All` of that task's `TaskDetails` have `ThisDetailFinishesTheTask == false`

```
Orders.Where(order => order.Tasks.Any(task => 
    task.TaskDetails.All(taskDetail => taskDetail.ThisDetailFinishesTheTask == false)));
```

Comment: that seems legit, and it might even be more clear to understand what happens instead of having an exclamation mark somewhere lying around which you might look over quite easily